# What foliage would grow best on a terraformed Moon?

Tags: terraforming

Assuming that:

- There are all climates found on earth
- There are no diseases
- All plants grow to their mature age
- The moon has a very thin atmosphere

Comment: A very thin atmosphere and all climates found on Earth are contradictory.

Comment: You mean still very thin atmosphere after terraforming? If so how thin, mars thin, or thin for earth or moon thin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ipomoea alba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipomoea_alba), obviously.

Realistically, no Earth plants would grow without both a thick enough atmosphere or some other means to reduce UV damage, and a atmospheric pressure and temperature which allow for liquid water, which [does not happen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_water) on the Moon.